# What is the solution of [citation] in Google scholar search results? Link is also not available to click on results

Tags: google-scholar

Our Google scholar was working properly but suddenly we are getting [citation] error by which all the articles are available on Google Scholar but we or anyone will not be able to visit as link is also not there. All our articles are facing the same issue so is there any problem from web server or hosting side? what should be the solution? Please help.
I have also attached screen shot where [citation] is mentioned and also there is no link.

Example:
[CITATION] Use of detergents in the analysis of fibrous feeds. IV. Determination of plant cell-wall constituents PJ Van Soest, RH Wine - J. Assoc. Off. Anal. Chem, 1967

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsxVi.png]

Answer (score 0):

This message is telling you that someone published a paper (A) in which the authors of paper A cited

Use of detergents in the analysis of fibrous feeds. IV. Determination of plant cell-wall constituents PJ Van Soest, RH Wine - J. Assoc. Off. Anal. Chem, 1967.

I'll call the Van Soest and Wine paper B.

Google has access to the citation in paper A.  However, Google Scholar can't find paper B in its data.  This could be because Google's data is limited, or it could be because the author of paper A made an error in the citation (e.g. by including the wrong year.)

You should not cite paper B based only on the citation of B in paper A.

When you encounter this situation, the best approach is to use Google Scholar and other databases such as the Web of Science to search for the original paper but not specifying all of the details in the citation.  You might for example find a paper with a similar title by the same authors that was published a year later.